# Locust in the distributed mode loses/overwrites data in custom listeners for report_to_master/worker_report hooks

Tags: python, elasticsearch, locust

That's what I'm trying to achieve: the only instance of publisher in Elasticsearch, which is running on the master and, which, with a certain number of records in a certain queue, collected from workers with a multiple number of users, will send them directly to Elasticsearch, and at the end of the test, all the records that remain in the queue will be sent with `bulk`.

At the moment, this is implemented by using event hooks `report_to_master` and `worker_report`, but some records are lost, as I suspect after debugging, sometimes the variables of `response_data` and `another_data` overwrite the new value before sending them through `on_to_master`.

```
import gevent
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps
from time import perf_counter
from uuid import uuid4

from gevent.queue import Queue
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
from locust import SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, task, between, events
from locust.runners import WorkerRunner


def on_worker_report(es):
    def inner(data, **kw):
        if (rd := data.get('response_data')):
            es.response_queue.put_nowait(rd)
        if (ad := data.get('another_data')):
            es.another_queue.put_nowait(ad)
    return inner


@events.init.add_listener
def on_init(environment, **_kw):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        es = Elastic(environment)
        environment.runner.greenlet.spawn(es.run)
        on_worker_report_listener = on_worker_report(es)
        environment.events.worker_report.add_listener(on_worker_report_listener)


class Elastic:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
        self.env = env
        self.response_queue = Queue()
        self.response_index = 'response'
        self.another_queue = Queue()
        self.another_index = 'another'
        self.bulk_size = 10
        self.env.events.quitting.add_listener(self.on_quit)

    def to_es(self, data, index):
        bulk(self.es, ({'_index': index, '_source': doc} for doc in data))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.response_queue.qsize() >= self.bulk_size:
                data = (self.response_queue.get_nowait() for _ in range(self.bulk_size))
                self.to_es(data, self.response_index)

            if self.another_queue.qsize() >= self.bulk_size:
                data = (self.another_queue.get_nowait() for _ in range(self.bulk_size))
                self.to_es(data, self.another_index)

            gevent.sleep(1.0)

    def on_quit(self, **kw):
        response_data = (self.response_queue.get_nowait() for _ in range(self.response_queue.qsize()))
        self.to_es(response_data, self.response_index)
        another_data = (self.another_queue.get_nowait() for _ in range(self.another_queue.qsize()))
        self.to_es(another_data, self.another_index)


class MyBaseTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root_path = '/'
        self.events = self.user.environment.events
        self.events.report_to_master.add_listener(self.on_to_master)
        self.response_data = None
        self.another_data = None

    def validate(self, response):
        print('Validating', response)
        self.prepare_response_data(response)

    def on_to_master(self, data, **kw):
        data['response_data'] = self.response_data
        data['another_data'] = self.another_data
        self.response_data = None
        self.another_data = None

    def prepare_response_data(self, response):
        data = {
            'timestamp': datetime.now().isoformat(),
            'url': response.request.url,
            'uuid': str(uuid4())
        }
        self.response_data = data

    def prepare_another_data(self, name, time):
        data = {
            'timestamp': datetime.now().isoformat(),
            'name': name,
            'time': time,
            'uuid': str(uuid4())
        }
        self.another_data = data

    def timer(name):
        def decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
                s_perf = perf_counter()
                ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                d_perf = perf_counter() - s_perf
                self.prepare_another_data(name, d_perf)
                return ret
            return inner
        return decorator


class MyMainTask(MyBaseTask):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.task_path = '/api'

    def action_1(self):
        with self.client.get(self.root_path) as response:
            self.validate(response)

    def action_2(self):
        with self.client.get(self.root_path) as response_1:
            self.validate(response_1)

        with self.client.get(self.task_path) as response_2:
            self.validate(response_2)


class MyTest(MyMainTask):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def on_start(self):
        print(f'Start {self}')

    @MyBaseTask.timer(name='Step 1')
    @task
    def step_1(self):
        self.action_1()

    @MyBaseTask.timer(name='Step 2')
    @task
    def step_2(self):
        self.action_2()

    @task
    def stop(self):
        self.interrupt()


class MyUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [MyTest]
    wait_time = between(1.0, 5.0)
```

I also tried to use variables in the user space, not test, but it also did not give the result (a dot means the same code since the past example):

```
...
class MyBaseTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    ...
    def on_to_master(self, data, **kw):
        data['response_data'] = self.user.response_data
        data['another_data'] = self.user.another_data
        self.user.response_data = None
        self.user.another_data = None
    
    def prepare_response_data(self, response):
        data = ...
        self.user.response_data = data

    def prepare_another_data(self, name, time):
        data = ...
        self.user.another_data = data
        
    ...
    
...

class MyUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [MyTest]
    wait_time = between(1.0, 5.0)

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.response_data = None
        self.another_data = None
```

Another option was to use a list to combine the values, which should be in the queue, and check the already existing entries in it, but it led to the effect that part of the records do not fall into the queue (the problem that was before) and part of the records duplicated despite checks. This I followed using prints and comparison of uuids what were pushed into ES.

```
...
def on_worker_report(es):
    def inner(data, **kw):
        if (rd := data.get('response_data')):
            for e in rd:
                es.response_queue.put_nowait(e)
        if (ad := data.get('another_data')):
            for e in ad:
                es.another_queue.put_nowait(e)
    return inner

...

class MyBaseTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.user.response_data.clear()
        self.user.another_data.clear()
    
    def on_to_master(self, data, **kw):
        data['response_data'] = self.user.response_data
        data['another_data'] = self.user.another_data

    def prepare_response_data(self, response):
        data = ...
        if data not in self.user.response_data:
            self.user.response_data.append(data)

    def prepare_another_data(self, name, time):
        data = ...
        if data not in self.user.another_data:
            self.user.another_data.append(data)
    
    ...

...
class MyUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [MyTest]
    wait_time = between(1.0, 5.0)

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.response_data = []
        self.another_data = []
```

I even tried to collect the `data` dict for `report_to_master` and call the `fire` method manually, but then even statistics breaks.

```
class MyBaseTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    ...
    
    def prepare_response_data(self, response):
        data = ...
        stats = self.user.environment.stats
        data_report = {}
        data_report['stats'] = stats.serialize_stats()
        data_report['stats_total'] = stats.total.get_stripped_report()
        data_report['errors'] = stats.serialize_errors()
        stats.errors = {}
        data_report['response_data'] = data
        self.events.report_to_master.fire(client_id=self.user.environment.runner.client_id, data=data_report)
```

Also, a number of problems that I encountered:

Event hooks `request`, `request_failure`/`request_success` are not suitable, since the transfer of additional data is required, which is not provided for by these hooks, as well as they work in the same place where they're registered, so no master-worker communication is presented. From here it turns out that I also can't use own custom hook, as there will be no communications that in the locust is organized as a client-server via `zmq`. Also, the data that I transmit in this mode must be serializable, so I can't pass, e.g, a full `Response` object to handle it already on the master, but must convert to some kind on worker.

Perhaps I implement something absolutely wrong, so I should return to the very beginning, for example, it was now thinking about the creation of instance of `Elastic` precisely on workers and then the communications with the master may not be needed, but on the other hand, I wanted workers to send requests, while the master would be loaded by creating and processing logs.

Comment: Hi! This question is a bit broad for stackoverflow. If you can create a minimum reproducible code example for what you feel is broken (because there is something broken, right?), you could create a github issue.

Comment: Also: one question/issue at a time..